# How to not proceed with adding a value if its an empty/null string?

Tags: javascript, object

My code reads data somewhere and then adds them as values to properties in an object. I made a for loop to iterate over the items in the list so they can each belong in their own cute little object but here is a problem: sometimes there's no value to a property and I wan't to know what I can do to intercept that before it finishes being declared to the property. Maybe replace the empty string with a word or something.

Here is an example code and lets say the title on iteration #3 is going to be an empty "" string. how do I intercept that?

```
var counter = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < nyData.results.length; i++) {
  if (_.indexOf(uniqueItems, nyData.results[i].id)) {
    continue;
  }
  if (!_.indexOf(uniqueItems, nyData.results[i].id)) {
    var index = i;
    counter++;
    let putParams = {
        TableName: "Articles",
        Item: {
          "title": nyData.results[i].title,
          "date": nyData.results[i].published_date,
          "abstract": nyData.results[i].abstract,
          "source": nyData.results[i].source,
          "views": nyData.results[i].views,
          "author": nyData.results[i].byline,
          "section": nyData.results[i].section,
          "category": nyData.results[i].des_facet,
          "organizations": nyData.results[i].org_facet,
          "people_involved": nyData.results[i].per_facet,
          "country_subject": nyData.results[i].geo_facet,
          "id": nyData.results[i].id,
        }
    }
    db.put(putParams, function(err) {});
  }
}
console.log(`Total of ${counter} new articles were inserted into database.`);
callback(null);
```

Comment: `console.log(\`Total of ${counter} new articles were inserted into database.\`);` What language is this?

Comment: Please stop poisoning your question titles with fake tags. We have an actual tags system.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Looks like JavaScript, as the OP says....?

Comment: @qxz: Doesn't look like JavaScript to me. `${counter}` is Perl (or PHP?) and I don't know what language those backticks are valid in.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's called a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (ES6 feature).

Comment: @qxz: Hah! Okay, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if( myVar) {
}
```

will only be true, if the variable is not:-

Empty
Null
undefined
0
false
....and a few more.